# Find $\int{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have problem with this integral:
$$\int{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}}dx}$$

My idea was to solve it with substition of 
$$t=\sqrt[6]{x+1}$$
because
$$\int{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x+1}}dx}=\int{\dfrac{x}{(\sqrt[6]{x+1})^3+(\sqrt[6]{x+1})^2}dx}$$
So then 
$$x=t^6-1$$
and $$dx=6t^5dt$$
Putting it into the integral I got
$$\int{\dfrac{t^6-1}{t^3+t^2}6t^5dt}$$
Then
$$6\int{\dfrac{t^9-t^3}{t+1}dt}$$
And after dividing it I have this integral
$$6\int{t^3(t^3-1)(t^2-t+1)dt}$$
with which I don't know what to do.

I would be thankful for help.

Comment: Multiply those polynomials.

Comment: In principle this is very straightforward. Multiply the polynomial directly. A binomial times a trinomial isn't too lengthy. Were you looking for something more elegant?

Comment: No I am just an idiot :-)...I was happy that I realized to do it with substition and when I saw this I was confused and I completely forgot just to multiply it. Thx :-)

Comment: @UmbertoP. If you want it to write the multiplication into an asnwer, I can "Find your answer the best" and so this question would be ended and you will get some points...:-)

Comment: Sure, why not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle this is very straightforward. Multiply the polynomial directly. A binomial times a trinomial isn't too lengthy.

If you are looking for an elegant approach as opposed to a brute-force one, I'm not sure what would work.